# What role in a string has # when passing string parameters via JS (Fragment identifier)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have recently experienced a problem when passing string parameters via `JS` to controller action if string contains **#**, it would ignore the next parameter.

***JS***

```
window.location.href = $ele.data("url") + "?title=" + $ele.data("title") + "&employeeId=" + $ele.data("employeeid") + "&suggestionId=" + $ele.data("suggestionid") + "&statusId=" + $ele.val() + "&communicationId=" + $ele.data("communicationid");
```

***C#***

```
public ActionResult StatusUpdate(string title, Guid employeeId, Guid suggestionId,
        int statusId, Guid? communicationId)
    {
        var suggestion = new SuggestionView
        {
            SuggestionStatusId = statusId,
            SuggestionId = suggestionId
        };
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
    }
```

So if `$ele.data("title")` contains **#**, in the controller action the next parameter or more specifically `employeeId` in this particular case would come as `NULL`, and it wouldn't pass the data properly since `employeeId` is not a nullable `Guid`.

Why is a controller action ignoring parameters after the `#`?

Comment: Its called [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier), You can use `encodeURIComponent('#')` to send encoded data. Read [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: @Satpal Thanks, where is encodeURIComponent coming from?

Comment: Its native JavaScript method, I have provide link in my prev comment

Comment: @Satpal Cheers!